# Java: set value and check condition at same time

Tags: java

(In the process of writing my original question, I answered it, but the information might be useful to others, and I thought of a new question)

For instance:

```
int x;
if (x = 5) { ... }
```

Creates an error:
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean. (Because assignment doesn't return a
    boolean value)

However,

```
int x; 
if ((x = 5) == 5) { 
    System.out.println("hi!");
}
```

will print out "hi!"

And similarly,

```
String myString = "";
if ((myString = "cheese").equals("cheese")) {
    System.out.println(myString);
}
```

prints out "cheese"

Sadly,

```
if ((int x = 5) > 2) { ... }
```

does not work with an in-line declaration.  How come?  Can I get around this?

Comment: I think a biggest question is: *why* would you want to "get around" this?

Comment: I am super curious as to *why* also...  I must know why this is desirable.  :)

Comment: I was simply curious as to how it could be done.  I don't plan on designing anything in this fashion, I just thought it was an interesting question I came across when I needed to add certain functionality and thought this up as a [contrived] alternative.

Comment: @matt b: My "Can I get around this?" is not a plea for help, I was stumped as I thought this an interesting coding exercise, because it requires an incredibly specific knowledge of the language specifications and how grammars work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Sadly,

I suspect that most Java developers would heartily disagree with that sentiment ...

> ```
> if ((int x = 5) > 2) { ... }
> ```
>
> does not work with an in-line
>   declaration. How come?

It does not work because a declaration is not a Java expression, and cannot be used in an Java expression.

Why did the Java designers not allow this?  I suspect that it is a combination of the following:

- Java's syntactic origins are c and C++, and you cannot do this in C or C++ either,
- this would make the Java grammar more complicated and the syntax harder to understand,
- this would make it easier to write obscure / cryptic programs in Java, which goes against the design goals, and
- it is unnecessary, since you can trivially do the same thing in simpler ways.  For instance, your example can be rewriten this to make the declaration of `x` to a separate statement.

> Can I get around this?

Not without declaring `x` in a preceding statement; see above.

(For what it is worth, most Java developers *avoid* using assignments as expressions.  You rarely see code like this:

```
int x = ...;
...
if ((x = computation()) > 2) {
    ...
}
```

Java culture is to favour clear / simple code over clever hacks aimed at expressing something in the smallest number of lines of code.)

Comment: Yes, this is the correct explanation. Not the one about `scope`. +1

Comment: I'm just really impressed that you can use assignment + conditional, but you cannot use instantiation + assignment + conditional.  I understand that this is as a result of the grammar because (int x = 5;) does not return a boolean when evaluated in the compiler chain, it is not even a possible path down the chain because it is unsupported (and for good reason, although I don't understand why assignment is still OK, it should be a crime)

Comment: @sova - *"although I don't understand why assignment is still OK"*  Well, the Java team cannot go around removing language features.  That would break source code compatibility.

Comment: I definitely think this "feature" should be discouraged, and I think it's a pretty well-known problem that languages can't "lose" features once they've been added, but this is more like an oversight, and not a feature, in my opinion.  Wouldn't it be awesome if language grew in multiple directions (code clarity _and_ features) instead of just perpetually gaining new features without any improvements in clarity?  And you can always tell your compiler which version of Java you're using...

Comment: @sova - *"you can always tell your compiler which version of Java you're using..."*.  But think it through.  If they said language feature X is not available after Java 1.6, then people with applications that use feature X would be stuck at Java 1.6.  This would be a **bad thing** for a language whose primary market niche is enterprise applications.

Answer (score 1):

Your `x` only exists within the scope of the assignment, so it's already gone by the time you get to `> 2`. What is the point of this anyway? Are you trying to write deliberately unreadable code?

Your best way to get around this is to declare `x` in a scope that will remain valid throughout the `if` statement. Seriously though, I fail to understand what you're doing here. Why are you creating a variable that is supposed to disappear again immediately?

Comment: No, its not the case. If this were the case the compiler should say, "can't find symbol". But the compiler is complaining, "parenthesis expected". And FYI, code block is defined using {} not ().

Answer (score 1):

```
if ((int x = 5) > 2) { ... }
```

Yes this will not compile because you can't declare variables inside the condition section of `if` clause

Answer (score 0):

The `>` test will work fine, as long as you declare the int outside of the `if` condition.  Perhaps you are simplifying your condition for the sake of brevity, but there is no reason to put your declaration in the condition.

> Can I get around this?

Yes, declare your var outside the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't declare the int separately as you did in the == test.

```
jcomeau@intrepid:/tmp$ cat /tmp/test.java
class test {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  int x;
  if ((x = 5) > 2) System.out.println("OK");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java, `for()` allows initialization code, but `if()` doesn't.

Comment: This is exactly the behavior I was originally expecting, but I see why it is not now.

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare the variable in condition section. For example

```
for(int i = 0; j < 9; i++){...}
```

is completely valid statement. Notice we declare the variable in `for` but not in a condition clause, now look at this,

```
for(int i = 0; (int j = 0)<9; i++){...} // Don't try to make logical sense out of it
```

not allowed.